# GTM Not Writing to Page With Custom HTML Tag

Tags: google-tag-manager, schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to implement schema markup on my site using Custom HTML tags in Google Tag Manager. When I preview my changes, it works perfectly. However, when I push the tag live, it does not appear on my page.

I've had a similar issue with tags in preview appearing differently than in live. But when I tried looking into it, it I couldn't find an answer on why that would happen.

So I'm wondering if you have any insights into why this tag works in preview, but does not work live?

[image: HTML]

[image: Tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. We had an `X-XSS-Protection` header set to `1;mode=block` which was limiting Google Analytics from injecting scripts that could be considered an XSS attack.

This could have also happened with an incorrectly configured `Content-Security-Policy`.

The correct way to set up a `Content-Security-Policy` that allows Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager to inject scripts is outlined in [this Lunametrics article](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2017/07/20/using-google-analytics-google-tag-manager-content-security-policy/) (take note of Simo Ahava's comment after the post).